# Dart final and const list - How to explain this code block?

Tags: dart

I was looking for codes to understand the difference between final and const in dart. After I found some code blocks and changed a bit, the outputs were surprising for me. How to explain these outputs? What causes this difference?

```
void main() {
  final list1 = [1, 2];
  final list2 = [1, 2];

  print(list1);
  print(list2);
  print(list1 == list2); //false

  const list3 = [1, 2];
  const list4 = [1, 2];

  print(list3);
  print(list4);
  print(list3 == list4); //true
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const` means the object is created at compile time instead of when the program is running. Dart does also guarantee that if you create two `const` objects with the same arguments, it will both points to the same compile time object. This optimization is possible since `const` objects MUST be immutable and we can therefore safely just share the same instance multiple times.

The `==` operator will by default (and such also on `List`) check if two objects are the same as in the same physical object in memory.

Since your two `const` created lists are created with the same objects, the two lists variables, `list3` and `list4`, will end up pointing to the same exact object created by the compiler and therefore `list3 == list4` is going to be `true`.